# Error while trying to run the Client Code

Tags: python-3.8

[image]enter image description herePlease I am following a guide to create a Server that responds to the text a Client sends to it but in the reversed order. The Server code runs without any issue but the Client code is not working, its is giving the error message: "OSError:[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied"

Please I need help to resolve this.

Below is the code for both the Server and the Client:

#server.py

```
import asyncio
import socket

# Get the default "event loop" that we will run
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# notice our new "async" before the function definition


async def server_method():
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind(('localhost', 6789))
    server.listen(1)

    # await for a new client
    # The event loop can run other code while we wait here!
    client, _ = await loop.sock_accept(server)

    # await for some data
    data = await loop.sock_recv(client, 1024)
    data = data[::-1]

    # await for sending the data
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, data)

    # Close both the Server and Client connections
    server.close()
    client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run the loop until "server_method" is complete
    loop.run_until_complete(server_method())
```

#client.py

```
import asyncio
import socket

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
addr = ('localhost', 6789)


async def client_method():
    message = b'Hello Server!\n'
    client = socket.socket()

    client.setblocking(False)

    # await to establish a connection
    await loop.sock_connect(client, ('localhost', 6789))
    # await asyncio.get_event_loop().sock_connect(client, addr)

    # await to send the message
    print('Sending', message)
    await loop.sock_sendall(client, message)

    # await to receive a response
    response = loop.sock_recv(client, 1024)
    print('Server replied', response)

    client.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop.run_until_complete(client_method())
```

[image]

Comment: Add await in line 23; `response = await loop.sock_recv(client, 1024)` ; Then No error occurred. Could you run it in https://www.pythonanywhere.com/?

Comment: Hello Smart Manoj, I have attached the output I am getting after executing both the server.py and client.py code